# How do you prevent user from entering gibberish into user input and prevent them from using all caps or all lower case letters?

Tags: python

I am trying to make an input that would prevent a user entering an input like this "QWERTY" this "qwerty" or this "QW3RTY"
The input is for names so I want to make sure that it would need the user to have a capital letter at the start of their name "John" not "john"

I have tried to loop the question using while True: try and attempted to use .isalpha and .title but I couldnt seem to make it work

```
while True:
    try:
        name = input(str("What is your name? "))
    if name is not name.isalpha:
        print("Please Enter a Valid name")
        continue
    if name is not name.title:
        print("Please have a capital letter at the start of your name!")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

I expected for the if statements to work but it comes up with invalid syntax.

Comment: you forgot `()` in `isalpha()` and `title()`. And `try:` needs `except:`.

Comment: `input` doesn't need to be wrapped as `str`, as it will always produce `str` values

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is faulty ... but you've replicated it, even though the first `if` failed.  Correct your problems one at a time, rather than trying to write the whole program at once.

`name` is a string; `name.isalpha` is a function.
A string cannot ever be identical to a function.

I think what you want is

```
if name.isalpha():
```

Also, `try` *requires* an `except` clause to catch exceptions.  Again, add program features individually.  That way, when you hit an error, you'll be fixing only that one error.

See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing features one at a time is a much better place to start than to try to catch everything all at once. Also, make sure to call your functions, otherwise, they will be truthy:

```py
if str:
    print("True!")
else:
    print("False!")

True!

# compared to 
if str():
    print("True!")
else:
    print("False!")

False!
```

Functions are objects, and will not act Falsey.

```py
while True:
    name = input("What is your name? ") # no need for str function here

    # you can wrap this whole thing in a
    # try/except for ValueError
    try:
        if name.isupper() or name.islower() or not name == name.title():
            raise ValueError("Please include proper capitalization")
        elif not name.isalpha():
            raise ValueError("Use only alphabetical characters, please")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```